# Kentico 7 error Type or Namespace WorkflowManager could not be found

Tags: kentico

I am trying to setup a Kentico 7 patch 58 site. I downloaded Kentico installation manager 7 and created a new site. When I access the site I get the error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WorkflowManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:
Line 16:     protected TreeProvider mTreeProvider = null;
Line 17:     protected WorkflowStepInfo mWorkflowStepInfo = null;
Line 18:     protected WorkflowManager mWorkflowManager = null;
```

Please advise what I could be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using [web application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) project type and you didn't rebuild the project after applying the HF.

Please refer to: C:\Program Files (x86)\KenticoCMS\7.0\Hotfix70_58\Instructions.pdf (page 7)

Also look at the page 12 (Additional notes and workarounds) and check whether there are any manual steps you have to take.